# SwiftUI Navigation bar is push down when keyboard is on

Tags: swiftui

My code is quite straight forward

```swift
VStack {
            Text("Edit your mobile number for emergencies")
                .font(.largeTitleRubic)
            MobileNumberListItem(mobileCountryCode: $selectedCountryCode, mobileNumber: $selecteMobileNumber)

            Spacer()

            ButtonPrimary(isEnabled: true, caption: "CONFORM", cornerRadius: .infinity) {
                update()
            }.frame(width: 225)
        }
```

But got strange behaviour when the keyboard is on

[image]

[image]

Comment: That might be the safe area shrinking (b/c of the keyboard), making the `Spacer` shrink. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Make sure you only have one NavigationView and that it is at the top of all views. Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example to debug, otherwise we all just guess and no real help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your view isn't in a ScrollView.

Since you cannot scroll the content, SwiftUI tries to move all the contents of the view up so that its visible to the user.

You can try the following:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        Text("Edit your mobile number for emergencies")
            .font(.largeTitleRubic)
        MobileNumberListItem(mobileCountryCode: $selectedCountryCode, mobileNumber: $selecteMobileNumber)

        Spacer()

        ButtonPrimary(isEnabled: true, caption: "CONFORM", cornerRadius: .infinity) {
            update()
        }.frame(width: 225)
    }
}
```

Because everything it now wrapped in a scrollview, your "conform" button might not be at the bottom anymore, but you can achieve this by setting the frame min height and using GeometryReader.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard will pop-up with out adjusting the view's layout:

> .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom )

```
VStack {
        Text("Edit your mobile number for emergencies")
            .font(.largeTitleRubic)
        MobileNumberListItem(mobileCountryCode: $selectedCountryCode, mobileNumber: $selecteMobileNumber)

        Spacer()

        ButtonPrimary(isEnabled: true, caption: "CONFORM", cornerRadius: .infinity) {
            update()
        }.frame(width: 225)
    } // VStack
      .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom )
```

When using a NavigationStack, this modifier would **also** need to be used on the top most view containing the navigationStack.

```
var body: some View {
    
    VStack{

        NavigationStack(path: $router.path) {...} // NavigationStack
        
    } // VStack
      .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom )

} // body
```